# Defining routes in asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm trying to define a Put api method with this syntax:

/api/orders/12/orderdate

where 12 is orderId, orderdate is an action method with 2 parameters: int orderId, OrderDate orderdate.

What could be the route definition for this method?

Comment: Is orderdate the action name or a date parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Orders",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{orderId}/{action}"
        );
```

You can also be more explicit if you wish:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Update Order Date",
            routeTemplate: "api/orders/{orderId}/orderdate"
            defaults: new { controller = "Orders", action = "OrderDate" }
        );
```

And your action method would look like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage OrderDate(int orderId, OrderDate orderDate)
{
    // implementation
}
```